# how to put wait cursor for easyupload vaadin

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7

I am using mutlitupload(from easy upload add on) vaadin to upload file.
After the upload is done, I do some processing to show the uploaded file to user in tabular format. This process sometimes takes time.
how can I change the regular mouse pointer to wait cursor and disable the background screeen, so user would know something is happening.
Right now, I get a progress bar when the upload is happening, but after upload, its kinda idle which makes user think that nothing is happening.
My code is following:

```
class MyFileUpload extends MultiFileUpload
{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1916326819603193170L;

    @Override
    protected void handleFile(File file, String fileName, String mimeType, long length)
    {
        Collection<String> selectedValues = (Collection<String>) deduplicationOptionGroup.getValue();
        String content;
        try
        {
            content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath()), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));

         // This part takes time
            presenter.save(content, referenceFileType, selectedValues.contains(TITLE_OPTION), selectedValues.contains(JOURNAL_OPTION), selectedValues.contains(YEAR_OPTION));
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.getStackTrace();
            // presenter.save(content, referenceFileType, selectedValues.contains(TITLE_OPTION),
            // selectedValues.contains(JOURNAL_OPTION), selectedValues.contains(YEAR_OPTION));
        }
        UI.getCurrent().removeWindow(uploadWindow);
        uploadWindow = null;

    }

}
```